# Calling a Python function without passing it an argument - animate(i)

Tags: python, function, animation, matplotlib

I'm struggling to work out what's going on in this code and adapt it to get my own code to work. I'm not sure if it's something universal to Python functions or if it's something specific to the matplotlib animation package.

The code comes from [Jake Vanderplas animation tutorial](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) but similar examples of it around the web.

This is the animation function which is called:

```
# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
```

and this is the line that calls it:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```

animate takes the argument `i` but he is calling it without the variable `i`. Does `animation.FuncAnimation` somehow know to pass a value in there or how does this work?

Small aside - is that comma after the return statement of any significance?

Comment: `return line, == return (line,)`

Comment: Most probably, `FuncAnimation` calls the function `animate` with the frame as an argument.

That 'comma' means that the return is a tuple, if it weren't there, the return would be a single variable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, would really not have guessed that, this is my first experiment with animation, needed to something, thought it might have been about leaving out a newline, but obviously not. Will read up on the return statement must be a bit more to it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When seeing cases like this one, it's good to remember that **functions**, *like everything else in Python*, **are objects**. As such, they can be, among other things, stored in data structures, be re-assigned a name and be *passed as another functions argument*.

Take a look at the documentation for **[`animation.FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation)**:

> `class matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, **kwargs)`
>       Bases: matplotlib.animation.TimedAnimation
>
> **Makes an animation by repeatedly calling a function func, passing in (optional) arguments in fargs.**

So it simply takes the *function object* `animate` (in this case) and calls it with the arguments supplied in `fargs` (which if not specified, default to `None`).

**Note**: After viewing the source for [**`FuncAnimation`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py) I realized that `fargs` are simply **additional arguments** to be passed to the function `animate` and if `fargs=None` they default to an empty tuple meaning no arguments. (In this case `fargs` should not indeed be specified since `animate` takes only one argument)

The function `animate` is called using: `func(framedata, *self._args)`  where `framedata` relates to the `frames` argument passed initially and `self._args` are any arguments supplied via `fargs`.

The full call made (`self._func` in the following is actually your `animate` function):

```
 # Call the func with framedata and args. If blitting is desired,
 # func needs to return a sequence of any artists that were modified.
 self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
```

So yup, internally matplotlib calls your function with the `framedata` argument.

---

As the trailing comma in the `return`, that means that it will return the value as a tuple with a single element, `line` in this case. It's the same as the following:

```
>>> i = 1,
>>> i
(1,)  # tuple with single element
```

Comment: Thanks for that, y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i)) is expecting a value for i however, what is it going to do with None?

Comment: If you do not explicitly pass a new value in `fargs` it is probably going to raise a `TypeError` since it will use `None`. You need to specify a value for `i` by passing it in `fargs` like `fargs=10` (for example).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Jim that tuple with a single element was helpful to see. If you check the code on the site https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/ there are no fargs unfortunately and I've run it, no errors..

Comment: O.k I viewed the source and it actually passes an `iterable` constructed from the `frames` argument. It gets somewhat comfusing and I don't think you need to go deeper here. Just know that **internally**, **it does** call the function supplied (`animate`) with an argument it constructs :-).

Comment: I think you've got it @Jim, at least very close to what is going on. I think my animation will soon be working and will forget about this detail as you suggest. What happens when you pass an empty tuple into y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i)), I suppose the i just disappears and you get y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01))  and it gets its x value from the line above.

Comment: No no, if `i = ()` then `0.1 * ()` is again a `TypeError` :-P. Like I said, your function will finally be called with `i = framedata`, this is fixed and doesn't change. (when you feel a bit comfortable with Python, check out the source for it, it will help you understand how this works in much more detail than I could present in my answer.

Comment: Ok, one day might be able to understand that source better when I understand the classes better. For now, inserted a line `print >> f, i,` after `def animate(i):`  to write the value of i to a file. Of course opened and closed the file.. This is his animation example which is the moving sine waves. Let it run for about 30 seconds and stopped it. Can confirm that the contents of the file looked like this: `0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 197 198 199 0 1 2 3 ... ` So that's what I also wanted to know, `i` starts at 0 and is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

## is that comma after the return statement of any significance?

yes, it is shorthand syntax for tuple and so...
`return line, == return (line,)`

## Does animation.FuncAnimation somehow know to pass a value in there or how does this work?

I have not looked into matplotlib, but I think you are confused about the syntax of it. One can pass in function as an argument. See below

```
def foo(func,x,y,z): # foo takes in func,x,y,z
    return func(z) # foo returns func(z)
    
def bar(a): # bar takes in a, return a*a
    return a*a
    
print foo(bar,2,3,4) # foo returns bar(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In this call you pass the **function reference**, in the FuncAnimation, it can call your function with correct parameters.
2. Yes, it makes the response as tuple.

Answer (score 0):

For the part where you asked,

> I'm not sure if it's something universal to Python functions

I invite you to read the second line of this tutorial.
http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html

Basically, you need to keep in mind while programming in Python that,

> Everything is an object and it can be passed around like a normal object.

Which means, classes, functions, integers, strings, list, sets, tuples...everything. Because if you see the base type of all these different data types, you would be surprised to find, everything at its very basic is `<type 'type'>`

Further reading: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html#basic-concepts